# Not able to install Docker compose in Linux

Tags: linux

I am not able to install docker compose on my Linux system.getting below error after running installation command:

```
~$ sudo apt-get -f install docker-compose
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 code : Depends: libnotify4 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libnss3 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libxkbfile1 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgconf-2-4 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libsecret-1-0 but it is not going to be installed
 docker-compose : Depends: python-cached-property but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python-docker (>= 1.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python-dockerpty (>= 0.4.1) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python-docopt but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python-enum34 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python-jsonschema but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python-requests (>= 2.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python-six (>= 1.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python-texttable but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python-websocket but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python-yaml but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Can anyone please help me out? I tried sudo apt-get clean as well but no use

Comment: Did you try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages like the error message says?

Comment: it says E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: So, try `sudo apt-get -f install` with no packages :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the easiest way to install docker-compose is via pip:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install docker-compose
```

Answer (score 3):

**Install Docker Compose on Linux systems**
 1. Run this command to download the latest version of Docker Compose:

```
$ sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.22.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

2. Apply executable permissions to the binary:

```
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

3. Test the installation.

```
$ docker-compose --version
```

For more detail information please refer docker manuals: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

Comment: I tried this command and get docker-compose --version usr/bin/docker-compose no such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.17.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

docker-compose --version
```

Pay attention to the "v" in v2.17.2. Remove the v for versions 1.x.

Answer (score 0):

Hellow, you can't get packages depend. Mayby your system is old and repozytory packages is not suported e.g. in Wheezy. Mayby is other problems. I dont now, becous you have not written more information about your system that you use (e.g. system version, repository list  - cat /etc/apt/sources.list, e.t.c.). I suggests you to use use this oficial tutorial to install docker-compose in debian with the official docker page - src: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/ (you can use `curl` to download latest binary docker-compose and adapt it for use or using `pip` tool to install docker-compose - according to the official tutorial) or using the solution given in this page (e.g. `pip` tool).  I used docker oficial tutorial to reinstall docker-compose in my system (to latest version). Was helpful. I use Debian 9 "Stretch" (latest, stable).

Ps. do not forget remove older installation docker-compose when you use other solutions to installation docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to install docker compose.  It is availble from dockerhub as a docker image ,... so you can run it from docker.